# PHP Substr Function Trimming Problem

Tags: php, substr, html-encode

I'm using below code for triming titles and show it [recent posts section](http://screencast.com/t/ODRmMzVlOTQt) on my [blog](http://www.sivrisinema.com):

```
<?php global $post;
$releaseDate = get_post_meta($post->ID, "gosterim_tarihi", true);
foreach( $images as $image ) {
    $title = get_the_title();
    if (strlen($title) > 20) { $title = substr($title, 0, 20) . '&hellip;'; }
    $attachmentimage=wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image->ID, 'large' );
    echo '<li><a href="'. get_permalink() .'" title="' . $title . '"><img src="'. $attachmentimage[0] .'" alt="'. $title .'" />'. $title .'<span>Gösterim Tarihi: ' . $releaseDate . '</span></a></li>';
} ?>
```

But there are problem with HTML character entities. When i use `substr` function for trim a title, `substr` function trimming HTML character entities too.

So i tried to use [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) function but i can't do it very well.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$output = htmlentities(substr(html_entity_decode($input), 0, 20));
```

This will decode all entities so `substr` won't break anything. After that you can encode all characters back to their entities.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function there eg:

```
substr(strip_tags($title), 0, 20);
```

This will deal only with the title excluding any html chars.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I think `strip_tags` function is stripping HTML tags. But i want to strip HTML character entities (http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/entities/).

Answer (score 0):

Use This Function

```
<?php
  function keephtml($string){
          $res = htmlentities($string);
          $res = str_replace("&lt;","<",$res);
          $res = str_replace("&gt;",">",$res);
          $res = str_replace("&quot;",'"',$res);
          $res = str_replace("&amp;",'&',$res);
          return $res;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be cleaner if you can leave the html-encoding until the last minute, e.g. when you actually echo the $title string. Of course, that means you have to remember to encode all the strings yourself.