# Substr not working with html tags and entities

Tags: php, string, html-entities, substr

I have gone throught the following question:
[substr() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885957/substr-not-working) but it did not work for me :(

I am facing the same problem. I am using `nicEditor` and for at the time of insert, I do `htmlentities(addslashes(urlencode($description)))`
and when I view the description? It shows me correctly, but when i use `substr()` it returns nothing. 
like:

```
substr($description,0,10)
```

`$description` contains the content and it is fine, present in db, works without `substr()`

Comment: You have to add more precise details. It is impossible for anyone here to _guess_ where the data comes from, what exactly you do and what you expect to come out.

Comment: I guess it is cleared that my `substr()` is not showing any thing when there are `HTML entities` are present, it works finr without `HTML` entities.

Comment: To `substr()` the variable content is just a string. It does not know about html. Could it be you have a problem with _outputting_ broken html tags in a browser (so in html)?

Comment: html tags are not broken, the question i linked to my question, there it is mentioned that `substr()` doest not work if there are html tags

Comment: No, I just checked with a simple script and for me `substr()` works as expected even when html tags are inside the haystack.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? Can you provide a Solution or further details as asked before so others don't get stuck again.

Comment: No, it did not solve my problem, for now, just storing the description without `html`tags

Comment: Any solutions to this question? Or you just achieved it by just changing the eidtor?

Answer (score -3):

Please provide a var_dumb()
 of **$description** and a bit more code before $description is filled in, so we can see if there is an other problem.

Try this one

> Use mb_substr for multibyte character encodings like UTF-8. substr
>   just counts bytes while mb_substr counts characters.
>
> substr() works with singlebyte only
>   http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php

Source: [PHP Substr Function Trimming Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124209/php-substr-function-trimming-problem)

> This happens because in UTF-8 characters are not restricted to one
>   byte, they have variable length to match Unicode characters, between 1
>   and 4 bytes.
>
> A safe way of cutting these strings without losing anything is by
>   using the mb_substr PHP function instead. It works almost the same way
>   as substr but the difference is that you can add a new parameter to
>   specify the encoding type, whether is UTF-8 or a different encoding.

Source: http://osc.co.cr/extracting-a-substring-from-a-utf-8-string-in-php/

Comment: This is NOT an anwer, it should have been a comment. This is a cheap trick to reserve an early datetime for your answer. How cheap.

Comment: I can not comment with 8 Rep! sorry :/ and now i'm further away of writing comments.

Comment: Have you thought about the reaons _why_ new users are meant to wait a few days? Sorry, no offense meant, but answers like this are really annoying to everyone consulting this question afterwards... What did you gain with this "answer"? What is the point in it?

Comment: Everythings fine. I will hold back next time until i can comment. Post edited and a solution try provided

Comment: Though is is true, that there are issues with using an 8bit function in a unicode situation this _still_ is not an answer. it is a wild guess at most.

Comment: Okay, i'll remember everything you mentioned for further anwsers. Should i delete this answer?